# Segue to a View Controller from my AppDelegate removes my UI Tab Bar

Tags: ios, swift

I am having a problem when performing segue from my AppDelegate. I am using this code to do a segue from appdelagate:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "MyStoryboard", bundle: nil)
let viewController: MyViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "myviewcontroller") as! MyViewController
let rootViewController = self.window!.rootViewController as! UINavigationController
rootViewController.show(viewController, sender: self)
```

When I use this, my UITabBar is removed. I want to segue to a ViewController that is not a TabBar item and retain my UITabbar. I am also using navigation. How should I approach this?

Answer (score 0):

To show the tab , you need to do the push from 1 of the tab vcs , and it should be embeded  inside a navigation and use

```
let nav = self.window!.rootViewController as! UINavigationController
if let tab = nav.viewControllers.first as? UITabBarController , 
  let innerNav = tab.viewControllers.first as? UINavigationController {
    innerNav.pushViewController(viewController,animated:true)
}
```

Comment: I am performing segue from appdelegate. When I use your code the `let tab = nav.viewControllers.first as? UITabBarcontroller` return `Use of undeclared type 'UITabBarcontroller'` error

Comment: @RussVirtuoso updated , don't use segues when you need to present something from AppDelegat

Comment: what should i do? @Sh_Khan